# Infix to Postfix with function support

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, infix-notation, postfix-notation

There are many algorithms to convert infix to postfix all over the web. But my question is how to make that to support functions? For example sin(x+y)*z.

I will appreciate a code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for an algorithm that gives you the conversion infix to postfix including function call support, you can use the below pseudocode(which looks like python code). I have written this for my case but not yet tested thouroughly. If you find any bugs please let me know.

I have also written a Java implementation for the same.

Also, there are few things to note about this implementation:

1. This algorithm assumes a stream of tokens in infix. It does not parse a expression string. So each token can be identified as an operand, operator, function call etc.
2. There are 7 different kinds of tokens:

   - Operands X, Y etc
   - Left Paranthesis - (
   - Right Paranthesis - )
   - Operators - +, *
   - Function call starts - sin(
   - Function call ends - sin( x **)**
   - Comma - ,
3. Function call starts are denoted by `[` character in the algorithm and function call ends are denoted by `]`. Please note that function call termination is a different token than Right Paranthesis `)` although they may be represented by the same character in the string expression.
4. Every operator is a binary operator with precedence and associativity as their usual meaning.
5. Comma `,` is a special binary operator with precedence of `NEGATIVE INFINITY` and associativity as LEFT (same as + and *). Comma operator is used to separate the arguments of a function call. So for a function call:

   ```
   f(a,b,c)

   first comma separates a and b
   second comma separates a,b and c

   So the postfix for the above will be 
   ab,c,f
   ```

   > You can view Comma operator as a add to list function which adds the second argument to the list specified by the first argument or if both are single values it creates a list of two values.

#### Algorithm

```
infix_to_postfix(infix):

    postfix = []
    infix.add(')')
    stack = []
    stack.push('(')
    for each token in infix: 
        if token is operand:
            postfix.add(token)
        if token is '[':
            stack.push(token)
        else if token is operator:
            if stack is empty OR 
               stack[top] is '(' or stack[top] is '[':
                stack.push(token)
            else if (operator)token['precedence'] > stack[top]['precedence'] OR
               ( (operator)token['precedence'] == stack[top]['precedence'] AND 
                 (operator)token['associativity') == 'RIGHT' ):
                stack.push(token)     
            else
                postfix.add(stack.pop())
                stack.push(token)
        else if token is '(':
            stack.push(token)
        else if token is ')':            
            while topToken = stack.pop() NOT '(':
                postfix.add(topToken)
        else if token is ']':
            while True:
                topToken = stack.pop()
                postfix.add(topToken)
                if topToken is '[':
                    break

        else if token is ',':
            while topToken = stack.peek() NOT '[':
                postfix.add(topToken)
                stack.pop()
            stack.push(token)
```

Answer (score 4):

Although @mickeymoon algorithm seems to work, I still had to make some adjustments(didn't work for me) so I think it can be helpful for somebody another implementation(Java like implementation). Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

```
Stack<Token> stack = new Stack<>();
List<Token> result = new ArrayList<>();
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm
// with small adjustment for expressions in functions. Wiki example works only for constants as arguments
for (Token token : tokens) {
    if (isNumber(token) || isIdentifier(token)) {
        result.add(token);
        continue;
    }
    if (isFunction(token)) {
        stack.push(token);
        continue;
    }


    // if OP(open parentheses) then put to stack
    if (isOP(token)) {
        stack.push(token);
        continue;
    }
    // CP(close parentheses) pop stack to result until OP
    if (isCP(token)) {
        Token cur = stack.pop();
        while (!isOP(cur)) {
            if (!isComma(cur)) {
                result.add(cur);
            }
            cur = stack.pop();
        }
        continue;
    }
    if (isBinaryOperation(token)) {
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            Token cur = stack.peek();
            while ((!isBinaryOperation(cur)
                    || (isBinaryOperation(cur) && hasHigherPriority(cur, token))
                    || (hasEqualPriority(cur, token) && isLeftAssociative(token)))
                    && !isOP(cur)
            ) {
                // no need in commas in resulting list if we now how many parameters the function need
                if (!isComma(cur)) {
                    result.add(cur);
                }

                stack.pop();
                if (!stack.empty()) {
                    cur = stack.peek();
                }
            }
        }
        stack.push(token);
        continue;
    }

    if (isComma(token)) {
        Token cur = stack.peek();
        while (!(isOP(cur) || isComma(cur))) {
            result.add(cur);
            stack.pop();
            if (!stack.empty()) {
                cur = stack.peek();//  don't pop if priority is less
            }
        }
        stack.push(token);

    }
}
while (!stack.empty()) {
    Token pop = stack.pop();
    if (!isComma(pop)) {
        result.add(pop);
    }

}
return result;
```

I tested it with various complex expressions including function composition and complex arguments(doesn't work with example from Wiki algorithm). A couple of examples(e is just a variable, min,max, rand - functions):

**Input:** (3.4+2^(5-e))/(1+5/5)

**Output:** 3.4 2 5 e - ^ + 1 5 / + /

**Input:** 2+rand(1.4+2, 3+4)

**Output:** 2 1.4 2 + 3 4 + rand +

**Input:** max(4+4,min(1*10,2+(3-e)))

**Output:** 4 4 + 1 10 * 2 3 e - + min max

I also tested it with complex function with three arguments(where each argument is an expression by itself) and it words fine.

Here is the github for my [java function](https://github.com/vtsyvina/sim-it/blob/master/src/main/java/sim/grammar/SimItGrammarParser.java#L238-L326) that takes the list of tokens and returns the list of tokens in postfix notation. And here is [the function](https://github.com/vtsyvina/sim-it/blob/master/src/main/java/sim/grammar/SimItGrammarParser.java#L407-L467) that takes the output from first function and calculates the value of the expression

Answer (score 3):

Thats quite easy: It work with functions too, the regular operators you use (like +,-,*) are functions too. Your problem is, that what you consider "function" (like sin) is not in infix, but they are in prefix.

To come back to your problem: Just convert these prefix functions into postfix (you should find prefix to postfix on the web too - my assumption is that you dont know the "prefix" term) beforehand.

**EDIT**: Basicaly it is nothing more that first convert the arguments and output them in sequence and append the name of the function afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The code you'll have to work out yourself.  Using your specific case as an example might help get you started; the postfix form of `sin(x + y) * z` would be:

> x y + sin z *

Note that in this one example some operations operation on two values (`+` and `*`), and others one (`sin`)

Answer (score 1):

binary operators like `+` can be considered as `+(x,y)`
Similarly Consider sin, cos, etc functions as unary operators. So, sin(x+y)*z can be written as `x y + sin z *`. You need to give these unary functions special treatment.

Comment: This only works for single argument functions - e.g. exp(x,y) wont work.