# Evaluating mathematical expressions passed in as strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wish to make a mathematical function ( `f(x,y)` in this case ) with multiple variables, only two in this case, `x` and `y`, which evaluates a mathematical expression which is in a string format initially.

For example,
If the string is

```
s = "2*x + sin(y) + x/(y-3.0)"
```

The function f(x,y) must be equivalent to

```
def f(x,y):
    return 2*x + sin(y) + x/(y-3.0)
```

The String is constant throughout the program and is initialized at the start.

The function will be called thousands of times. So I wish it to be very efficient.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: you've looked at sympy?

Comment: Either use `eval`, but then be sure that your input is trusted, or use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org).

Comment: Why does it need to be a string?

Comment: It's because, it will be input from the user

Comment: How complex the string should be? What operators do you need?

Comment: @vz0 the string can be very complex, and will need almost all functions in the python math module plus basic arithmetic operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you stay away of [eval](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and using a proper library to do the mathematical job at hands, one of the favourite candidates is sympy, which is described as:

> SymPy is a Python library for symbolic mathematics. It aims to become
>   a full-featured computer algebra system
>   ([CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system)) while
>   keeping the code as simple as possible in order to be comprehensible
>   and easily extensible. SymPy is written entirely in Python.

With sympy, you could solve your problem like this:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

eq = parse_expr("2*x + sin(y) + x/(y-3.0)")

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        s1 = eq.subs({"x": x, "y": y})
        s2 = s1.evalf()
        print s1, "-->", s2
```

Output:

```
0 --> 0
sin(1) --> 0.841470984807897
sin(2) --> 0.909297426825682
sin(3) --> 0.141120008059867
1.66666666666667 --> 1.66666666666667
sin(1) + 1.5 --> 2.34147098480790
sin(2) + 1.0 --> 1.90929742682568
zoo --> zoo
3.33333333333333 --> 3.33333333333333
sin(1) + 3.0 --> 3.84147098480790
sin(2) + 2.0 --> 2.90929742682568
zoo --> zoo
5.00000000000000 --> 5.00000000000000
sin(1) + 4.5 --> 5.34147098480790
sin(2) + 3.0 --> 3.90929742682568
zoo --> zoo
```

zoo means "complex infinity". For more info, read the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html).

Of course, you could use one of the many existing python parsers out there or just writing yours as suggested by vz0. I'd recommend you learn more about [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) though.

Comment: Sympy uses `eval` under the hood, so this is not safer; see https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10805

Answer (score 1):

Without using SymPy you should create your own parser, for example by [converting the infix expression to a postfix expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708195/infix-to-postfix-with-function-support), which are very easy to evaluate once in this notation. Mathematical functions are just unary operators like `-x`.

Answer (score -5):

Use the `eval` function
`return eval(s)`

Comment: And make sure to surround it with `try ... except` to catch the many horrible errors that might occur

Comment: And make sure the input is 100% safe

Comment: Plus you might need to ensure that the evaluation takes place with the right namespaces for locals and globals

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind already, but eval(s) will evaluate the string every time the function is called. Considering the function will be called thousands of time. Is there something more efficient?

Comment: @dark32 Structure your script differently so that you don't make the same calculations 1000s of times. E.g. store the string and output in a dictonary as key/value pairs and look it up before computing.

Comment: @Alvaro Marques Most of the time, the arguments given will be different.