# Shunting-yard algorithm with function support

Tags: c++, pseudocode, infix-notation, shunting-yard

i found this implementation of the Shunting-yard algorithm over the internet
([Infix to Postfix with function support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708195/infix-to-postfix-with-function-support))

```
infix_to_postfix(infix):

postfix = []
infix.add(')')
stack = []
stack.push('(')
for each token in infix:
    if token is operand:
        postfix.add(token)
    if token is '[':
        stack.push(token)
    else if token is operator:
        if stack is empty OR
           stack[top] is '(' or stack[top] is '[':
            stack.push(token)
        else if (operator)token['precedence'] > stack[top]['precedence'] OR
           ( (operator)token['precedence'] == stack[top]['precedence'] AND
             (operator)token['associativity') == 'RIGHT' ):
            stack.push(token)
        else
            postfix.add(stack.pop())
            stack.push(token)
    else if token is '(':
        stack.push(token)
    else if token is ')':
        while topToken = stack.pop() NOT '(':
            postfix.add(topToken)
    else if token is ']':
        while True:
            topToken = stack.pop()
            postfix.add(topToken)
            if topToken is '[':
                break

    else if token is ',':
        while topToken = stack.peek() NOT '[':
            postfix.add(topToken)
            stack.pop()
        stack.push(token)
```

i try to port it to c++ but I can't understand where I'm wrong
that is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <stack>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string magic(string& infix){
       const string ops = "-+/*%^";
       string postfix;
       stringstream ss;
       stack<char> s;

       string token;
       infix+=")";
       s.push('(');
       for(int c = 0; c<infix.length(); ++c){
        for(int op = 0; op<ops.length(); ++op){
            if(infix[c] == ops[op])
                postfix+=infix[c];
        }
        for (int op = 0; op<ops.length(); ++op){
            if(infix[c]=='['){
                s.push(infix[c]);
            }else if(infix[c] == ops[op]){
                if(s.empty() || s.top()=='(' || s.top()=='[')
                    s.push(infix[c]);
                else if(0){
                    // cose con le precedenze
                }else{
                    s.pop();
                    postfix+=s.top();
                    s.push(infix[c]);
                }
            }else if(infix[c]=='('){
                s.push(infix[c]);
            }else if(infix[c]==')'){
                while(s.top() != '('){
                    s.pop();
                    char topc = s.top();
                    postfix += topc;
                }
            }else if(infix[c]==']'){
                while(true){
                    s.pop();
                    char topc = s.top();
                    postfix+= topc;
                            if(topc == '[')
                                    break;
                }
            }else if(infix[c]==','){
                while(s.top()!='['){
                    char topc = s.top();
                    postfix += topc;
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.push(infix[c]);
            }
        }

    }

    return postfix;

   }

   int main() {

      string infix = "[ sin ( 2 , 5 ) ] + 3 ^ ( 4 * ( 5 * ( 6 - 1 ) ) )";

      cout << "infix:   " << infix << '\n';

      cout << "postfix: " << magic(infix) << '\n';

      return 0;
    }
```

if you could not develop in C ++ what alternatives do I have? are there algorithms that do similar things more suited to the problem? all code answers are welcome, thanks.

Comment: It's usually a good habit to take arguments that are const references, as in `const std::string&` to make it clear they don't get modified. It's also a good idea to kick the `using namespace std` habit and make it clear where those structures and classes come from.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: *but I can't understand where I'm wrong that is my code* -- Not to be flippant, but maybe the issue is that you didn't understand the original algorithm enough, and relied on a "line-by-line" translation from that algorithm to C++ and hoped it worked.  If you understood in detail what you are doing in the algorithm, then at the very least, you would identify where your code is wrong (maybe not how to fix it, but at least identify the line(s) of code that are not working correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your translation of the code from that answer, including one fairly obvious error in the answer itself, which is that the second `if` (`if token is '['`) should be `else if`. But note that the condition in the first `if` is `if token is operand`, but your translation is, roughly, `if token is operator`. Those two issues are certainly enough to prevent your code from working as desired.

Beyond that, it's important to read the notes in the cited answer, which point out that the pseudocode is based on the input having already been tokenised; the code is not intended to be applied directly to the input. In particular, numbers and variable names should be single elements in the token stream. Also, see note 3 which explains where `[` and `]` come from; they are not in the input stream, so they must be created by the tokeniser.

It's generally helpful to try to understand how an algorithm works when you're trying to write an implementation, particularly when what you are porting is pseudocode. (The most important thing about pseudocode is that it is not code, so it will never have been tested. It's quite common for even very experienced coders to not notice little errors which slipped into pseudocode. If there were a way of running the pseudocode, such errors would be detected immediately, but since there isn't, the errors will appear when a concrete implementation is tested. In short, *caveat receptor*.)

There's a reasonable explanation of [the shunting-yard algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). In particular, the pseudocode on that Wikipedia page handles function calls provided the names of the functions are known.

For yet another discussion of shunting yard, including a note on how to recognise function calls and unary operators (prefix and postfix) while tokenising the input, see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392115/1566221), which also includes pseudocode.

An interesting fact about the three Shunting Yard presentations is that they each have their own style of translating function calls to postfix. The concrete problem you need to solve is that a postfix function call is ambiguous unless you somehow know how many arguments are used. The parentheses in the infix call make the argument count explicit, but a parenthesis-free representation like postfix needs a different mechanism.

Using the comma as a binary operator which builds a parameter list, as in the code you are trying to port, is an interesting strategy. However, the pseudocode as presented cannot handle functions with no parameters. (Also, the fact that the `[` token must also contain the function name is not very well explained.)

The Wikipedia code, on the other hand, relies on recognising the identifiers used as functions. And it requires each such function to have a well-known number of parameters. That's ok in a calculator, where functions are usually restricted to things like `sin` and `digamma`, but it's problematic in a general purpose programming language.

My solution inserts a `CALL` operator into the postfix output; as a note indicates, a practical implementation should also insert the number of arguments supplied as an additional value just before `CALL`. The implementation details are not well-explained, though. (Sorry!)